# SQL Developer - What is the SUM function doing?

Tags: sql, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to have a table that displays the total of a handicap score for a team during a certain match, and at a certain bowling alley.

This is my Goal:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
SELECT TOURNEYID || ' ' || tnm.TOURNEYLOCATION "Tournaments", 
  MATCHID "Match ID", t.TEAMNAME "Team Name", 
 TO_CHAR(SUM(bs.HANDICAPSCORE), '99,999') "Total Handicap Score"
FROM TOURNAMENTS tnm
  JOIN TOURNEY_MATCHES tym USING (TOURNEYID)
  JOIN MATCH_GAMES m USING (MATCHID)
  JOIN BOWLER_SCORES bs USING (MATCHID)
  JOIN BOWLERS b USING (BOWLERID)
  JOIN TEAMS t USING (TEAMID)
GROUP BY t.TEAMNAME, TOURNEYID, tnm.TOURNEYLOCATION, MATCHID
ORDER BY TOURNEYID ASC, "Total Handicap Score" DESC;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I can see that my issue lies with the SUM function, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm very new to SQL, so any tips, or advice you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear what the desired result is.

Comment: My desired result is to use the SUM function to gather every bowler's handicap score on a certain team, during a certain game. My SUM function is coming up with more points than should be available.

Comment: If I understand you, you should be grouping by bowler, team, and game.  You aren't grouping by the bowler, and you are grouping by tournament, not by game.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I follow. Thank you for helping out, btw.

Comment: You said you wanted the sum of the scores per bowler, and per game and team, correct?  You are not including the bowler id or the match id in your group by clause, and you are grouping by tournament info.  That isn't congruent with how you described your desired result.   I might be misunderstanding how you described the desired result.

Comment: I see your confusion. I meant that I wanted to calculate the SUM of all the bs.HANDICAPSCORE from every player on one team during a certain game, and not every bowler's actual score. Also, MATCHID is included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: My guess is JOIN BOWLER_SCORES bs USING (MATCHID) lacking BOWLERID in the USING is at least part of the reason.